# Change Password (Nuxt and Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, vue-cli

I am trying to change a password from a user account, but I got the following error:

> user.updatePassword is not a function

```
 <script>
import { auth } from '@/server/firebase'

export default {
    data(){
        return{
            newPassword: '',
            repeatPassword: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        resetIt(){
            let user = auth.currentUser.uid;
            let getNewPassword = this.newPassword

            // console.log(user, getNewPassword)
            user.updatePassword(getNewPassword).then(() => {
            console.log('It works!')
            }).catch(() => {
            console.log(error)
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: user is set to id, your need `auth.currentUser.updatePassword(getNewPassword)`, though you obviously need check currentUser is defined first

Comment: It worked xD jesus thank you so much! @LawrenceCherone